# Workaround for primitive-type pass by reference

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm running into a problem, and not an expert of async/rxjs development.

Let me explain my problem:

I have an angular service `TimeoutService` which only contains a  `processTimeout()` method:

```
  processTimeout(timeout: NodeJS.Timeout, stillLoading: boolean): void {
    if (timeout !== undefined) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        if (stillLoading) this.dialog.open(LoadingDialogComponent);
    }, this.TIMEOUT_DURATION_MS);
  }
```

`processTimeout()` does the following:

- Takes a `NodeJS.Timeout` as parameter, and a `stillLoading` `boolean`.
- first it checks if timeout is already on and clear it if so.
- Then i set my timeout and if at the timeout callback the `stillLoading` value is `true` (which always is because when i pass it as parameter to the `processTimeout` method from `componentA` the value is `true`), I open a dialog saying that request is taking to much time.

Problem is, the `stillLoading` boolean passed to method is an attribute of my standard angular components (for example lets call it `ComponentA` that has a `boolean` `loadingA` attribute ), and I already know that js/ts has pass-by-value for primitive types:

It is set to true when I call my api service and set to false when loading is completed (when subscribe to my api  request has been done).

But setting the value of `loadingA`  to false occurs after I call the `processTimeout()` method from my service.

1. So my question is, what is the best way/ best practice so the boolean used in  `processTimeout()`  stays a reference or pointer (the same for me but I do not really know how Js/Ts works behind the scenes, but a variable should have an internal memory / DOM  Hex address) or even observable or something so the value of `stillLoading` in `processTimeout()` stays the same as my attribute `loadingA` of my `componentA` ? (Attribute `loadingA` is passed as `stillLoading` parameter and  is also a primitive `boolean` type in `componentA`).

Because of the nature of the timeout that makes the code inside it execute after the timeout, i need the boolean value at that time (from the `componentA`), and not the value it was when passed-by-value in the method.
I'm down to listen to every possible solution, and if possible respecting ts and angular best practices.

2. While writing the question, I also think I'll need the same solution for the timeout object too (But as it is an object it shall already be passed-by-reference right ?)

Thanks.

Tried: not a lot to be honest because I prefer some advice before losing hours on this problem, had an idea to pass a newly instanciated observable pointing on my `componentA` `loadingA` attribute, but I'm not sure at all of my comprehension of the way observables works for this kind of cases.

Expecting: the `stillLoading` method parameter in `processTimeout` being the same variable (same memory address)  than my `componentA` `loadingA` boolean attribute, or any workaround solution/clues on tools i can use to fullfill my need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## METHOD 1:

The code does not necessarily need to be on the service, you can create a common class that two children inherit, that contain this code. This will ensure that the function has access to the component variables, because each child will have its own scope!

export class Common {

```
  processTimeout(timeout: NodeJS.Timeout, stillLoading: boolean): void {
    if (timeout !== undefined) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        if (stillLoading) this.dialog.open(LoadingDialogComponent);
    }, this.TIMEOUT_DURATION_MS);
  }
```

}

child

```
export class ParentA extends Common {
    loading: false;

    constructor(private timeoutService: TimeoutService) {
        super()
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.timeoutService(5000, this.loading);
        this.loading = true;
    }
}
```

This can be done with any number of children!

---

## METHOD 2:

> As you said you can pass by reference and ensure the service has the latest value!

In your component, you can call it like

```
export class ParentA {
    loadingWrapper = {
        loading: false,
    }

    constructor(private timeoutService: TimeoutService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.timeoutService(5000, this.loadingWrapper);
        this.loadingWrapper.loading = true;
    }

}
```

in your service you can change it to

```
  processTimeout(timeout: NodeJS.Timeout, stillLoadingWrapper: {loading: boolean}): void {
    if (timeout !== undefined) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        if (stillLoadingWrapper.loading) this.dialog.open(LoadingDialogComponent);
    }, this.TIMEOUT_DURATION_MS);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Indeed I saw that creating a non-primitive object could do the trick. Works like a charm with a wrapper but too bad js/ts doesn't have any kind of pointer nor reference for primitive types

Comment: @RR1000 you can create a common class which is inherited by two components, this will ensure no problems will come since both will share their own unique variable, let me update my answer